# Android observeable in viewmodel only works once

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-mvvm

I am using android architecture components and following a tutorial from [here](https://github.com/Eli-Fox/LEGO-Catalog). This tutorial uses single source of truth strategy with local cashing using room and retrofit. I have implemented this part in my app and it works well. But in one Fragment I am facing the problem. The problem is that i have 4 buttons on activity and by clicking any button the data is filtered based on category say Category A category b etc. When I first load the fragment the data is displayed as expected but when I click on 2nd button to get data for category B the old data is showed and new data is never refreshed. 
Here is my code. 
In fragment inside oncreateview i have this observer

```
 private fun getCategory() {
        viewModel.categorys.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
            when (result.status) {
                Result.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    progressDialogue.hideDialog()

                    Log.d("category", "On success")
                    val item = result.data
                    setAdapter(item)
                }
                Result.Status.LOADING -> {
                    progressDialogue.showDialog()
                    Log.d("category", "On loading")
                }
                Result.Status.ERROR -> {
                    Log.d("category", "On Error")
                    progressDialogue.hideDialog()
                    Snackbar.make(binding.root, result.message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

this is my view model

```
class CategoryViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: CateRepository) : ViewModel() {
         var categorys = repository.mCate// ***this value not changes after 1st run***   
   }
```

this is my repository

```
class CateRepository @Inject
constructor(
    private val daoCat: DaoCat,
    private val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource,
     private val request: String
) {
    val mCate= resultLiveData(
        databaseQuery = {
            daoBundles.getAllCategories(BaseClass.Category)
        },
        networkCall = { remoteDataSource.getBundles(request) },
        saveCallResult = {
            daoCat.deleteAndInsert()
        })
```

My question is how can i refresh this value on button click
             ***var categorys = repository.mCate//*** 
**Update 1**

This is my click listener

```
binding.btnGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            val dao = AppDatabase.getInstance(BaseClass.appContext).bundlesDao()
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.btnHybrid -> {
                    BundleParams.setBundleType(BundleTypes.Hybrid.type)
                    getSelectedBundles(BundleTypes.Hybrid.type)
                }
                R.id.btnVoice -> {
                    BundleParams.setBundleType(BundleTypes.Voice.type)
                    getSelectedBundles(BundleTypes.Voice.type)
                }
                R.id.btnSMS -> {
                    BundleParams.setBundleType(BundleTypes.SMS.type)
                    getSelectedBundles(BundleTypes.SMS.type)
                }
                R.id.btnData -> {
                    BundleParams.setBundleType(BundleTypes.Data.type)
                    getSelectedBundles(BundleTypes.Data.type)
                }
                R.id.btnFavourites -> {
                    BundleParams.setBundleType(BundleTypes.Favorites.type)
                    getSelectedBundles(BundleTypes.Favorites.type)
                }
            }
        }





private fun getSelectedBundles(mType: String) {
        viewModel.updateCategory()
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like your `resultLiveData` is buggy

Comment: maybe this could help https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to add method to `ViewModel` and call it when button is pressed:

```
class CategoryViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: CateRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val categories: LiveData<Result<PromotionDetails>> = MutableLiveData<Result<PromotionDetails>>()

    // call this method when button is pressed
    fun updateCategory() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { // launch a coroutine
        val result = repository.resultLiveData()
        (categories as MutableLiveData).postValue(result) // update result value in main thread
    }
}

class CateRepository @Inject constructor(...) {

    fun resultLiveData(): Result<PromotionDetails> {
        return resultLiveData(
            databaseQuery = { daoBundles.getAllCategories(BaseClass.Category) },
            networkCall = { remoteDataSource.getBundles(request) },
            saveCallResult = { daoCat.deleteAndInsert() }
        )
    }
}
```

To use `viewModelScope` in `MainViewModel` class add dependency to build.gradle file:

> final LIFECYCLE_VERSION = "2.2.0-rc03" // add most recent version
>
> api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION"

Comment: What is <Result> here     val categories: LiveData<Result> = MutableLiveData<Result>()

Comment: what is <Result> here 
    val categories: LiveData<Result> = MutableLiveData<Result>()

Comment: It is just a model. You can change it to whatever your `resultLiveData` method is returned as generic type of `LiveData`.

Comment: I am getting type mismatch errer, 
    val categories: LiveData<Result<PromotionDetails>> = MutableLiveData()
        (categories as MutableLiveData).postValue(result) // type mismatch for post value
Required: Result<PromotionDetails>
Found: LiveData<Result<LIst<PromotionDetails>>>

Comment: This has also same behavior, Function from repository is only called once and same data is returned from view model

Comment: I've edited my answer. Can you try to return `Result<PromotionDetails>` instead of `LiveData<Result<PromotionDetails>>` from `resultLiveData` function? I guess you need to modify it somehow

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have changed the code as required. But when i call this line
        val result = repository.resultLiveData()
It only runs once. I have a break point in repository which hits only once.
and thus not getting new value from repository

Comment: Could you please show me button's click listener? Do you call `updateCategory()` when button is clicked?

Comment: Is `getSelectedBundles()` function called more than once?

Comment: Yes get selected bundle is called every time I click a button and the break point is hit in viewmodel

Comment: As I see all should work and `repository.resultLiveData()` must be called every time.

Comment: I am also expecting that this should work. But unfortunate :(

Comment: I am fetching data from this Method. Is this the cause or impacting in any way ? fun <T> resultLiveDb(
    databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>
): LiveData<Result<T>> =
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Result.loading<T>())
        val source = databaseQuery.invoke().map { Result.success(it) }
        emitSource(source)
    }

Comment: Yes, it may impact. Every time you call this method new instance of `LiveData` is created.

Answer (score 0):

I my case I try to implement a SwipeRefreshLayout to refresh data.

On the SwiperefreshListener =>

- Removed the observer
- Then add Observer again
- call action to refresh data.

I followed this same tutorial and i had the same issue.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
        vm.links.removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)
        vm.links.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { it?.let { observeLinks(it) } })
        vm.refresh()
    }
}

private fun observeLinks(result: Result<MutableList<Link>>) {
    when (result.status) {
        SUCCESS -> {
            binding.recyclerView.visibility = VISIBLE
            binding.progressBar.visibility = GONE
            binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
            knowMoreAdapter.clearItems()
            knowMoreAdapter.updateItems(result.data!!)
        }
        ERROR -> {
            Snackbar.make(
                binding.root,
                mContext.getString(R.string.error_loading_data),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            binding.progressBar.visibility = GONE
            binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        }
        LOADING -> {
            binding.progressBar.visibility = VISIBLE
            binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }
}
```

Then on View model class  I call the method refresh()

```
class KnowMoreVM @Inject constructor(private val repository: KnowMoreRepository) : ViewModel() {

var links = repository.observeSingleSource()

fun refresh() {
    links = repository.observeSingleSource()
}
```

}

Comment: The fix here is mediator live data